# .Net Regular Expression matching the string "C#"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression (using .Net's RegEx object) to match the sequence of characters "C#" with word boundaries.

So searching inside the string "I am a C# developer, but I am not a C#developper", I am trying to match the first "C#" (as a word) but not the second "C#" that is a part of a word.

- I have tried the pattern "\bC#\b", with no matches.
- I have also tried the pattern "\bC#\b" (trying to escape the #), no matches.

I have read somewhere that the pound (#) sign can be interpreted as word boundary.  Is this true?  And if so, how can we look for that string ("C#") as a word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\b` does not match between the pound sign and a space because they both match non word characters but is does match between the pound sign and the d char.

Instead of a second [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`, you could assert that what is on the right is not a non-whitspace `\S` character using a negative lookahead `(?!`:

```
\bC#(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbC%23%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=I+am+a+C%23+developer%2c+but+I+am+not+a+C%23developper)

As pointed out in the comments by [@elgonzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2819245/elgonzo), to prevent breaking the match when a non word char follows `C#`, you could use a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is either a non word char `\W` or assert the end of the string `$`

```
\bC#(?=\W|$)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbC%23%28%3f%3d%5cW%7c%24%29&i=I+am+programming+in+C%23%0d%0aI+am+programming+in+C%23.%0d%0aI+am+a+C%23+developer%2c+but+I+am+not+a+C%23developper&o=m)

Comment: I guess it is perhaps better to do a positive lookahead for a `\W` (non-word) character, otherwise punctuation marks like in `"I am programming in C#."` will spoil the soup. (Or even a positive lookahead including the text-end anchor like `(?=\W|$)`, if it should be permissible to match C# appearing at the very end of the input string)

Comment: @elgonzo If you use a positive lookahead using `\W` you expect that there  actually is a non word character, so that would not match `"I am programming in C#"` In that case, perhaps `\bC#(?![^\s.])` would better using a negated character class. https://regex101.com/r/nBoH8O/2/

Comment: as i said in my comment, if `C#` at the end of the input string should be matched too, use `(?=\W|$)`...

Comment: @elgonzo Ah, I think I have missed that part in your comment. I see that you mean. I will update the answer.

Comment: To be fair, i edited my comment and added that information shortly after posting my comment first. While i edited it some time before your comment reply appeared, you might have missed my edit. Sorry for any confustion that might have caused ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo No problem, thank you for the improvement!

Comment: This `(?=\W|$)` is another way of saying `(?!\w)`.

Comment: @revo `\w` does not match positions, whereas `$` does.

Comment: @KennethK. `\w` doesn't match a position but `(?!\w)` does. Just care to test.

Comment: @revo In effect, yes, but technically no it is not matching a position. It is matching the carriage return (or the newline itself in a *nix file) is not a word character--whenever the line does not contain either of those, and the target is at the end, there is trivially no matching word character. Personally, I'd opt for the more explicit expression because it more clearly conveys the intent. Brevity in regex can be either a boon or a curse.

Comment: @KennethK. When you say *technically* I assume you have some deep understandings of regular expressions and engines, which probably is not true. It doesn't mach a carriage return. `(?!\w)` asserts the very next character shouldn't be a word character. That's it. If there is no character following the current position, it means the same thing. [Check it here](https://regex101.com/r/6u6ae0/1/) and take a careful look at provided input string. There is no carriage return or newline character. The definition of regex is important. Do not make up one.

Comment: @revo OK, tiger:  "Match" was the wrong word to use. I was referring to the lookahead itself. But this seems to be a very meaningful point for you to have, so I'll let you have it. I'll retire with my "shallow" understanding of regex.

Comment: @KennethK. You call it a wrong word or whatever, the idea was totally wrong.

Comment: Ultimately I ended up using "\bC#(?=\W|$)" as my regex.  It works perfectly for my purpose.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following RegEx matches first word/last word/new line/spaces case insensitive

`/(:?^|\s)C#(:?$|\s)/i`